# Unicode being re-unicoded

Tags: python, unicode

I'm scraping info from Facebook which compiles weirdly. The source for a page returns the name "Trentemøller" as a regular string with a unicode character:

`Trentem\u00f8ller`

When I try to print that or commit it to a list `print u'%s' % name` or `print unicode(name)` it escape-sequences the backslash.

`u'Trentem\\u00f8ller'`

`['foo', 'bar', u'Trentem\u00f8ller']`

What is the proper way to treat this string? Ideally it would save it into the list in a `u''` but not the added backslash.

Comment: Are you copying and pasting anything, or are you writing code?  I can't see your code or your terminal so I don't know what is happening.  I also don't know how you are scraping data from Facebook.

Comment: I'm getting the source as a string with mechanize's Browser module. Then since their source is so weird I quickly cut out the part I want with `find()` statements because BeautifulSoup doesn't work. It's treated as a regular ASCII string the whole time as far as I know.

Comment: Wait... are you extracting it from HTML proper, or are you finding the data in say, some JSON or Javascript embedded in the HTML?

Comment: Straight HTML, as it appears when I "View source."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're in control of forming the unicode string, then use just one backslash:

```
>>> print u'Trentem\u00f8ller'
Trentemøller
```

If the regular string has already been formed by the screen scaper, you will need to re-evaluate the string to transform the [backslash escape sequences](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) into a real unicode characters.  The *[eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)* builtin would tempting, but it is safer to use [ast.literal_eval](http://docs.python.org/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead:

```
>>> import ast
>>> s = 'Trentem\u00f8ller'                   # a regular string
>>> print ast.literal_eval('u"""' + s + '"""')
Trentemøller
```

Comment: I ended up pulling the name from somewhere else that was compiled properly but this is great information. Thanks a lot.